# Google Drive through iOS’s picker disable .apk and .ipa files

Tags: ios, swift, attachment, uidocumentpickervc, disable-link

Here i attached my screenshot of google drive.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQjbK.png)

When i try to attach files from iOS application through UIDocumentMenuViewController , .ipa and .apk files are greyed out. it is disable so thats why i can't select it. So how can i enable it ??

Here is my code:

```
  UIDocumentMenuViewController *viewController = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
    viewController.delegate = self;
    //viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    viewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = [self popoverPresentationView];
    viewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = [self popoverPresentationRect];
    viewController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = [self popoverPresentationArrowDirection];

    [self.initialViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please anyone help.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: add more descriptions , `.apk` and `.ipa` ??

Comment: When i try to attach files from iOS application, this two files are grayed out. so thats why i can't select them. So how can this both of the files enabled ??